# Combine 2 firebase collections in one array

Tags: angular, firebase, collections

I would like to combine 2 firebase collections but I'm not sure how to do it.
In short I have a comment collection with all comments and replies and I need to add the image of each user from another collection with a search by email.

I have the following models:

```js
export class UserAdditionalInfo {
  constructor (
    public name: string, 
    public phoneCode: number,
    public phone: number, 
    public email: string,
    public userImg: string,
    public id: string
  ){}
}

//...

import { CommentReply } from './comment-reply.model';
export class Comment {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public email: string,
    public date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp,
    public comment: string,
    public id: string,
    public replies?: CommentReply []
  ){}
}

//...

export class CommentReply {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public email: string,
    public date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp,
    public comment: string,
    public id: string,
    public commentId: string
  ){}
}
```

and collections:

```js
  getComments() {
    return this.firestore
    .collection('comments', data => data.orderBy('date', 'asc'))
    .snapshotChanges();
  }
  
  //...
  
  getRegistration(email: string) {
    return this.firestore
    .collection('registrations', data => data.where('email', '==', email))
    .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

At the moment I take all comments an replies from getComments() and after that with a pipe by email transform I take the image from getRegistration(email: string). Its works but I would like a better solution when I combine both collections in one array. I not only have to combine them but also have to include the replies which are objects in the comment objects.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is very restrictive database, you can not perform an `INNER JOIN` in various collections, this is because Firesbase is a NOSQL database, focused mainly in performance and security. So I suggest insert the image url when you create a comment or comment reply using the `UserAdditionalInfo` already registered and stored in the web app related to the current user. In case of update/erase, I suggest to use an update/erase trigger related to `UserAdditionalInfo`.

In a nutshell, replicate the data you will require along the collections, in this case `userImg` and create triggers to maintain consistency along collections.

Well seeing your comments, I write you some code:

**In your webapp**

I start writing a service to store `UserAdditionalInfo`:

```ts
    export class UserService {
      private userAddtionalInfo: UserAdditionalInfo;
      ...
      login(userName: string, password: string){
        ...
        const userId = getUserId();
        if(userIsProperlyLogin){
          //Get user additional info from firestore
          userAdditionaInfo = getFromFirestoreUserAdditionalInfo(userId);
        }
      }
      getImageUrl(): string{
        return userAdditionInfo.userImg;
      }
    }
```

So, when you write a comment or comment reply:

```ts
//...
    export class CommentReply {
      constructor(
        public name: string,
        public email: string,
        public date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp,
        public comment: string,
        public id: string,
        public commentId: string,
        //Additional info
        userImageUrl: string
  ){}
}
//...
    export class Comment {
      constructor(
        public name: string,
        public email: string,
        public date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp,
        public comment: string,
        public id: string,
        public replies?: CommentReply [],
        //Additional info
        userImageUrl: string
      ){}
    }
//...
    export class CommentService {
      constructor(private userService: UserService){}
      ...
      private createComment(contain: string): Comment{
        ...
        comment.userImageUrl = userService.getImageUrl();
        return comment;
      }
      comment(contain:string){
        ...
        comment: Comment = createComment(contain);
        addCommentToFirestore(comment);
      }
      private createReply(contain: string): CommentReply{
        ...
        commentReply.userImageUrl = userService.getImageUrl();
      }
      reply(contain: string){
        reply: Reply = createReply(contain);
        addReplyToFirestore(reply);
      }
    }
```

Regarding `CommentReply`, I think move this data to a [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) instead an array, could be a good idea to allow queries related to this replies.

**In the cloud functions:**

I suggest create a function to trigger when `UserAdditionalInfo` changed or erased. [This is a good explanation about cloud functions in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). Also this explanation has a step by step guide to create your functions project.

About update `UserAdditionInfo` (using Nodejs 10 configuration in Cloud Function):

```ts
export const updateUserAdditionalInfoTrigger = functions.region('WRITE-HERE-YOUR-REGION').firestore
  .document(`UserAdditionInfo/{userAdditionalId}`)
  .onUpdate((change, context: functions.EventContext) => {
    //Check if email/imageUrl or any related data is changed
    //create a firestore transaction
    //Get all comments related with this user
    //Update all comments
    //Get all replies related with this user
    //Update all replies
    //End transaction
}
```

Comment: I also thought about this option - to save the userImg from UserAdditionalInfo. This is the easier option because I even have it saved in the local storage after user log in.

But the issue is when the user change his image, then in the comments will remains the old one. And if I do it like this after that I have to update many links in comments and replies and to do this I have to find them by comment id and after that to update the links, I don't think that this is a good option.

Comment: I tried to do something like the second example in this post:
https://medium.com/@joaqcid/how-to-inner-join-data-from-multiple-collections-on-angular-firebase-bfd04f6b36b7 with combineLatest from 'rxjs' but without success.

Comment: Thanks for your example, I think this is a good solution. I will try in this way later and i will add a comment.

Comment: Could you mark this answer as a good one? If you think it is a good solution.... I will be watching for any further problems you could have.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong or I missed something but in this way I will take the userImg url and I will save it in the comment collection just like url but in this way if the user change his image, in the comment collection the old link will remains. This is the reason to want to add the image from another collection dynamically because I have subscription on UserAdditionalInfo collection and this will change the url dynamically in the comment collection. Regarding the vote, ofc I will do it but when I have 15 reputation because at the moment the votes are locked for me as new acc.

Comment: I think you should check for what it means firestore trigger. When you update or erase a UserAdditionalInfo, a function is triggered to perform some kind of actions, so, in this case you could update properly the new url or even erase it in case a user additional info is erase. I create a full example to ensure always the image url is updated properly.